# Which is a Controller and which is HandlerMapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using [this](http://vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html) link to study Spring MVC. As described dispatcher-servlet is at the top handling all incoming requests.

It also describes that there is a HandlerMapping and a Controller. However, in the source code, only Controller is used. Which is HandlerMapping then? Is is not a separate file?

Or is it present in some other complex scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When no handler mapping is explicitly specified in configuation, [`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) is created and used by default.

From the article you linked:

"By default the `DispatcherServlet` uses the `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` to map the incoming request. The `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` uses the bean name as the URL pattern. Since `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is used by default, you need not do any seperate configuration for this."

Answer (score 11):

Controller and `HandlerMapping` are two different things in Spring MVC.
Controller is an actual java class which is used to process the request. We declare `@Controller` at the top of the class definition. 
Where as `HandlerMapping` is build in class of Spring framework. There are many hanlder mappings in Spring framework like `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`, `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` etc. By default, `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is used to map the request. This class searched in all controller classed to map the particular request with the method.

Answer (score 2):

Handler Mapping works as helper for Dispatcher servlet. It helps to identify appropriate controller bean to Dispatcher servlet. Default handler mapping bean is `DefaultUrlHandlerMapping`.

It identifies controller bean by url. It matches the name in URL with controller bean. If it matches it will return back it to `DispatcherServlet` and finally the servlet executes the business method of controller and returns ModelAndView object back to dispatcher servlet.